# Is there a "global" Ctrl + . (Jump to Error) shortcut in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Ctrl + .  brings me to en error in a file. But if my error view gives me more errors is there a shortcut which opens the next file and jumps to the error there?

Answer (score 7):

Currently... no, if you consider [bug 13300](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13300) from 2002!

> It would be cool if Next/Previous Error would work for all Java elements i.e.
>   would open/reveal the editor if the file is not in the active editor.

Status: WONTFIX.

Comment: Ummmpf. Ok, then we all have to work with "Strg + 7" to switch to a new view, then select the error and work with "Strg + ." again.